# spawning thread using a method without being static?

Tags: c#, multithreading

is it possible to spawn a new thread using a method that isn't static?  i have a program in wpf, i want to spawn a thread when it starts.  i'm trying to do this:

```
static Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SomeMethod));

private void SomeMethod()
{  
SendingMessage("hello");
SendingMessage("what's up");
}

private void SendingMessage(string x)
{
if (x=="hello")
      //Do something awesome here
if (x=="what's up")
      //do something more awesomer here
}

public MainWindow()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     thread.Start();
}
```

i believe i'm doing something wrong here.

Comment: Why do you think something is going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not going to compile because you trying to reference instance member within static context.
Simply move the `Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SomeMethod));` into your constructor and it should complile.